# How can I compare 5 random integers in a list and return different values if any 3 or more are equal

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a dice game that rolls 5 dice in `Python`, if any 3(or more) of the dice match then I'm trying to make it the number on the die *100.

For example 3 ones would be 300. I have the random number generator worked out and my gameboard set up, i'm just not sure of the logic required to compare items on a list one buy one like this and then assign values. My first attempt at writing something this complex.

Just looking to get led in the right direction. Maybe an iter.tools function I overlooked would be useful for this?

Honestly been thinking about it for awhile and googling around, but can't come up with an answer.

```
import random
import itertools


useddice = 0
game = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0]]


#def choose_die(dielist):
#def score(dielist, ):


def dielist():
    die1 = [random.randint(1,6)]
    die2 = [random.randint(1,6)]
    die3 = [random.randint(1,6)]
    die4 = [random.randint(1,6)]
    die5 = [random.randint(1,6)]
    dielist=[die1, die2, die3, die4, die5]
    print(dielist)
    return dielist

def game_board(game_map, dielist, just_display=False):
        print("  "+"    ".join([str(i) for i in range(5)]), '   <Dice Number, NOT ROLL')
        if not just_display:
            game_map[column] = dielist
        return game_map

dielist()
game_board(game, dielist, just_display=True)


#Everything from here is a work in progress

'''def win(score):
    if score >= 10000:
        print("Congratulations you won!")
        return 


play = True
players = [1, 2]
while play:
    game = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    game_won = False
    player_cycle = itertools.cycle([1, 2])
    game_board(game, just_display=True)
    while not game_won:
        current_player = next(player_cycle)
        played = False
        while not played:
            print(f"Player: {current_player}")


'''
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class:

```
from collections import Counter

die_values = [random.randint(1,6) for _ in range(5)]
die_value_counts = Counter(die_values)

for val, cnt in die_value_counts.items():
    if cnt >= 3:
       # ... do other stuff ...
       break
```

As a side remark, your code uses `dielist` both as a function name and a variable name. This can easily lead to problems and should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you want to do is define a method that rolls the dices. What you had works perfectly fine, but here's a slightly optimized version:

```
import random

def roll_dices():
  return [random.randint(0, 6) for n in range(5)]

dices = roll_dices()
print(dices) # outputs something like [5,2,4,5,0]
```

Now we'd like to know if any value appears 3 times or more. The shortest way to achieve this would be the following:

```
values = [x for x in set(dices) if dices.count(x) >= 3]
```

In short, this creates a new list of all the values that appear 3 times or more inside the `dices` list.

And here it is all together with the score and the players:

```
import random
import itertools

WINNING_SCORE = 10000;

class Player:
  score = 0

  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name


def roll_dices():
  return [random.randint(0, 6) for n in range(5)]

player_cycle = itertools.cycle([Player('John'), Player('Judy')])

while True:
  current_player = next(player_cycle)
  dices = roll_dices()
  values = [x for x in set(dices) if dices.count(x) >= 3]
  current_player.score += (sum(values) * 100)

  print('{player} just played, and their new score is {score}'.format(player=current_player.name, score=current_player.score))

  if(current_player.score >= WINNING_SCORE):
    break

print('{player} won the game with {score} points!'.format(player=current_player.name, score=current_player.score))
```

I've also thrown in a Player class to make it easier to work with the scores and such.